# This is kind of hard to explain, but how do I make the iterator variable not reset after being redefined in the loop?

Tags: python

```
def loop():
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 3:
            i += 5
        print(i)

loop()
```

This code outputs "1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9"
When i == 3, it gets set to 8. But on the next iteration, it gets reset to 4. How do I make it continue from "1, 2, 8" to "9"?

I've tried multiple things. Is there a way to use the continue keyword so it skips more than one iteration? Like this maybe:

`continue * 5`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Running your code - get this output: 0
1
2
8
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: This wont really work because I actually have to skip the iterations between 2 and 8

Comment: A different way to look at your problem is, "*how to loop over range of 1-10, but skip over 3-7*", which is a more practical problem and would lead you to better search results.

Comment: The next value of `i` has absolutely nothing to do with the previous value of `i` - it comes solely from the values produced by `range(10)`, and you have no way of affecting that.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a while loop instead.

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if i == 3:
        i += 5
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a for loop, you can do something like the following.

```py
def loop():
    skip, until = False, None
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 3:
            until = i+5
            skip = True
            continue
        elif skip:
            if i!=until:
                continue
            else:
                skip, until = False, None
        print(i)

loop()
```

We set two variables, `skip: bool` and `until: int`. The boolean `skip` means it is lower than that you want to skip to (in this case 8), and `until` stores the value 8. If it reaches 8, it will reset the `skip` and `until` variables.

But if a for loop is not required, use a while loop.

Ex)

```py
num = 0
while num<10:
    if num==3:
        num+=5
    else:
        num+=1
    print(num)
```